# Weak convergence, find an example for...

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Currently I’m studying for an exam and struggle with the following exercise:

Find prob measures $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2,..$ on $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ and functions $f, f_1, f_2,..$ all bounded and continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly as n tends to infinity and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ for all x in $\mathbb{R}$, **but**

$$ \int f_n d\mu_n \nrightarrow \int f d\mu \text{ as } n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take all the measures to be Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. Can you find your $(f_n)$'s in this case?

Comment: Thx for your response. Unfortunately I cant find the $f_n$‘s :/ I was playing around with some indicator functions but it doesn’t seem to work ..

Comment: Draw a triangle with base on the real axis from $0$ to $1/n$ and height $1$. Then draw the line from $1/n$ to $1$. Let $f_n$ be the function with this as the  graph and $f=0$.

Comment: That works! You are a genius, thx !!

Comment: I meant to say height $n$ not $1$.